# How to change the color of horizontal line on spinner and text hint

Tags: android

I use a library for my spinner.

**build.gradle**

```
 compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
```

**activity_register.xml**

```
 <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Material Design Spinner"
        android:textColorHint="#05ab9a"
        app:met_floatingLabel="normal" />
```

[image: spin]

How do I change the horizontal line and textHint color of the spinner to black just like the rest (Username, password, email) field.

Nb: android:TextColorHint not working.

OR anyone here has a code for a spinner that match my description. ??

Comment: Isn't it colorAccent that changes it?

Comment: Unknown attribute! @LunarWatcher